# fill a mulit-dimentional matrix with uniformly distributed random numbers with diffierent ranges

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I want to fill a 10000x2 matrix in OpenCV (v3.2) with random numbers in uniform distribution but with different ranges for each column and here is the problem with the following code:

```
Mat centers(10000, 2, CV_32F);
RNG rng(time(NULL));
rng.fill(centers, RNG::UNIFORM, Scalar(0, 0), Scalar(10, 1000));
```

I expect the first column to be randomly filled with values between zero and 10 and the second column to be filled with values between zero and 1000. But both columns are filled with values between zero and 10,
So I decided to implemented it in the following form.

```
Mat centers(10000, 2, CV_32F);
RNG rng(time(NULL));
rng.fill(centers.colRange(0, 1), RNG::UNIFORM, 0, 10);
rng.fill(centers.colRange(1, 2), RNG::UNIFORM, 0, 1000);
```

But it does not work either. I think because RNG::fill does not support noncontinuous matrices (which is not mentioned in the documentation)
So the only remaining way is to use for loop which is waste of time and performance. Am I doing sth wrong above or should I give up and use a for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply I made a mistake useing the RNG::fill api with multi-range distribution parameters. one should use multi-channels and not multi-columns matrices, even though they share the same underlying data structure. So, `Mat centers(10000, 2, CV_32F);` should be `Mat centers(10000, 1, CV_32FC2);`

Answer (score 0):

You have misinterpreted the API [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/dd6/classcv_1_1RNG.html#ad26f2b09d9868cf108e84c9814aa682d) of `RNG::fill()`, which clearly defines the parameters a and b as:

> a - first distribution parameter; in case of the uniform distribution,
>   this is an inclusive lower boundary.
>
> b - second distribution parameter;
>   in case of the uniform distribution, this is a non-inclusive upper
>   boundary.

So there is no mention in the documentation that you can pass multiple ranges in `a` and `b`. So the solution is to create two `Mat` of `1000 x 1` dimensions, use different values of `a` and `b` for both of them and later join both of them to create a unified mat with `1000 x 2` dimension.

```
cv::RNG rng = cv::RNG(0xFFFFFFFF);
cv::Mat centers(10000, 1, CV_32F);
cv::Mat centers2(10000, 1, CV_32F);
rng.fill(centers, cv::RNG::UNIFORM, cv::Scalar(0), cv::Scalar(10));
rng.fill(centers2, cv::RNG::UNIFORM, cv::Scalar(0), cv::Scalar(1000));

cv::Mat final;
cv::hconcat(centers, centers2, final);
```

Comment: Thanks that works but what is all about this phrase in the docs "In case of multiple-channel images, every channel is filled independently .." is that only for normal dist? and what is the use of Scalar if we are only allow to fill the whole matrix with same range values in uniform